# Java 8, Stream of Integer, Grouping indexes of a stream by the Integers?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I got a stream of Integers, and I would like to group the indexes of the elements by each element's value.
For example, `{1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4}` is grouped as Integer to list of indexes mapping:

```
1 -> 0, 1, 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 4, 5
4 -> 6
```

I have tried using stream, but with an additional class:

```
@Test
public void testGrouping() throws Exception {
    // actually it is being read from a disk file
    Stream<Integer> nums = Stream.of(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4);  
    // list to map by index
    int[] ind = {0};  // capture array, effectively final
    class Pair {
        int left;
        int right;

        public Pair(int left, int right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = nums.map(e -> new Pair(ind[0]++, e))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.right))
            .entrySet().parallelStream()
            .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue().parallelStream().map(ee -> ee.left).collect(Collectors.toList())
            ));
}
```

I have to read Stream since the Stream of Integer is read from a disk file in my application. 
I feel my way of doing it as above is pretty sub-optimal. Is there is a better or more elegant way to do it? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe using : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector- ? (Sorry, don't have Java8 right now to elaborate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little helper method for collecting:

```
class MapAndIndex {
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
    int index;

    void add(int value) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(value, x->new ArrayList<>()).add(index++);
    }
    void merge(MapAndIndex other) {
        other.map.forEach((value,list) -> {
            List<Integer> l=map.computeIfAbsent(value, x->new ArrayList<>());
            for(int i: list) l.add(i+index);
        } );
        index+=other.index;
    }
}
```

the entire operation becomes:

```
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = IntStream.of(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4)
    .parallel()
    .collect(MapAndIndex::new, MapAndIndex::add, MapAndIndex::merge).map;
```

When you need to track the indices which are unknown beforehand, you need mutable state and hence the operation called [“mutable reduction”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction).

Note that you don’t need a `ConcurrentMap` here. The `Stream` implementation will already handle the concurrency. It will create one `MapAndIndex` container for each involved thread and invoke the `merge` operation on two containers once both associated threads are done with their work. This will also done in a way retaining the order, if the `Stream` has an order, like in this example (otherwise your task of recording indices makes no sense…).

Comment: Plus one for "mutable reduction"

Answer (score 5):

1. You can use the [`IntStream#range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) method to get the index of each element.
2. Then use the [`IntStream.boxed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) method to convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream` with boxed `Integer`s
3. Group by mapping each index to the corresponding element from the array `i -> array[i]` and collecting the repeating elements into a list.

For example:

```
int[] array = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4};
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> result = 
        IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> array[i], Collectors.toList()));
```

**Update**:
If you don't have the array (and therefore the elements count), but a `Stream<Integer>`, you can *collect* the elements of the initial `Stream` into a `List<Integer>`. This way you will know the size of the `Stream` and then you can do:

```
Stream<Integer> = .... // The input stream goes here
//Collecting the input stream to a list, so that we get it's size.
List<Integer> list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
//Grouping process
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> result = 
    IntStream.range(0, list.size())
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> list.get(i), Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: What if I don't know the array length before hand?

Comment: And I don't get random access to the original array itself but stream.

Comment: So you get a `Stream<Integer>` and nothing more, correct?

Comment: Nothing more except for Stream<Integer> and know that it is of limited length.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
Stream<Integer> nums = Stream.of(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4);  

OfInt indexes = IntStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 1).iterator();
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();

nums.iterator().forEachRemaining(i -> result.merge(i, 
                                                   new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(indexes.next())), 
                                                   (l1, l2) -> {l1.addAll(l2); return l1;})
                                 );
```

Result:

```
{1=[0, 1, 2], 2=[3], 3=[4, 5], 4=[6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = nums.map(e -> new Pair(ind[0]++, e))
        .collect(groupingBy(p -> p.right, HashMap::new, 
                            mapping(p -> p.left, toList())));
```

This allows you to apply a mapping the the elements before they are added to the List.